# BLE bluetooth data sent after device disconnected on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

BLE device gets the data when it is disconnected from the gatt server.
I am trying to send data to the BLE device through the GATT server. When I try to send data which is command (string) to the BLE device, gattscancallback is called and it says write successful but nothing happens to the BLE device. But when I exit the application, the BLE device gets the data. I found that BLE device gets the data when it is disconnected to the gatt server. How do I solve this problem?
this is my GattCallback

```
private val gattCallback: BluetoothGattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
    override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
        if( status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE ) {
            disconnect()
            return
        } else if( status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS ) {
            disconnect()
            return
        }
        if( newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED ) {
            // update the connection status message

            Log.d(TAG, "Connected to the GATT server")
            gatt.discoverServices()
        } else if ( newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED ) {
            disconnect()
        }
    }
    override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)

        // check if the discovery failed
        if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Device service discovery failed, status: $status")
            return
        }
        // log for successful discovery
        Log.d(TAG, "Services discovery is successful")
        isStatuschanged = "connected"

        // find command characteristics from the GATT server
        val respCharacteristic = gatt?.let { BluetoothUtils.findResponseCharacteristic(it) }
        // disconnect if the characteristic is not found
        if( respCharacteristic == null ) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find cmd characteristic")
            disconnect()
            return
        }
        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(respCharacteristic, true)
        // UUID for notification
        val descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor = respCharacteristic.getDescriptor(
            UUID.fromString(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG)
        )
        descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
        gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)
    }

    override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt?,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic
    ) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic)
        //Log.d(TAG, "characteristic changed: " + characteristic.uuid.toString())
        readCharacteristic(characteristic)
    }

    override fun onCharacteristicWrite(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt?,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?,
        status: Int
    ) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status)
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic written successfully")
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Characteristic write unsuccessful, status: $status")
            disconnect()
        }
    }

    override fun onCharacteristicRead(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt?,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
        status: Int
    ) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status)
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic read successfully")
            readCharacteristic(characteristic)
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Characteristic read unsuccessful, status: $status")
            // Trying to read from the Time Characteristic? It doesnt have the property or permissions
            // set to allow this. Normally this would be an error and you would want to:
            // disconnectGattServer()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Log the value of the characteristic
     * @param characteristic
     */

}
```

this is my write function

```
fun write(message: String) {

    val cmdCharacteristic = BluetoothUtils.findCommandCharacteristic(bluetoothGatt!!)
    if (cmdCharacteristic == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find cmd characteristic")
        disconnect()
        return
    }

    cmdCharacteristic?.value = message.toByteArray()
    //bluetoothGatt!!.writeCharacteristic(cmdCharacteristic)
    val success: Boolean = bluetoothGatt!!.writeCharacteristic(cmdCharacteristic)
    if (!success) {
        Log.d("jay", "failed to write command")
    }
    Log.d("jay", "write succesful")
    //disconnect()
}
```

this is my disconnect function

```
fun disconnect() {
    Log.d("jay", "disconnect: bluetoothGatt is null? ${bluetoothGatt == null}")
    bluetoothDeviceAddress = null
    bluetoothGatt?.disconnect()
    isStatuschanged = "disconnected"
    bluetoothGatt = null
}
```

Comment: Why do you call writeCharacteristic twice?

Comment: sorry, I just tested my codes. Even I call it one time, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the `disconnect()` method? Because if you wrote that your central device sends data to the ble device when the application closes, it means that gattCallback's `onConnectionState` is triggered with a call to `newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED` and a call to the `disconnet()` method.

Perhaps the problem is that you explicitly need to specify the record type for the characteristic for example: `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT` or `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE`.

Also, there may be an error in the calling code, for example, if you use coroutines and manage them incorrectly

I recently had a similar problem when I solved it by specifying the feature write type and adding the `setCharacteristicNotification()` method

I had a similar problem recently, but I solved it by specifying the feature record type, and adding the setCharacteristicNotification method

Comment: I uploaded my disconnect function